# Get currently playing song of the Windows mediacontrol bar? (Java)

Tags: java, windows, audio, media, spotify

I want to create a java application which allows me to see the currently playing song windows is playing. Is there something for accessing to the windows media controls with java? (the bar on the top left which appears for example when you control the volume with media keys)

Thanks to y'all in advance! :D